# PHP TCPDF export specific pdf version

Tags: php, tcpdf, phpword

I'm developing an application using phpword and tcpdf to export a file to pdf.
But I needed this pdf to be exported in version 5.0, is there a way to do this? I don't find this configuration in the libraries.
thanks

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the highest version of PDF is 2.0. Could you clarify what "5.0" refers to?

Comment: Sorry, 
I meant PDF version 1.4, acrobat 5.x.
thanks

Comment: The core TCPDF object has a [setPDFVersion](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/172540dcbfdf8dc983bc2fe78feff48ff7ec1c76/tcpdf.php#L14088) that you should be able to use